# Can I use a variable when setting element id trough javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, increment

I am learning javascript and i was wondering whether I can use a variable in this type of scenario. 
I need a different id for each HTML element I create with the function in javascript. Would this work

```
<script>
    var i=0;
    function add()
    {
        i++;
        var textbox = document.createElement("input");
        textbook.setAttribute("type","text");
        textbook.setAttribute("id",i);
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, I am trying to set the id on the element with the i variable and i am not sure if I can do that.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it? Yes the code works

Answer (score -1):

Numbers should not be used as ID's for compatibilty reasons.

( [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) )

Apart from the typo this should work.
You should also call your add function to see the effect.

```
var i=0;
var textboxAmount = 2;
    function add()
    {
        i++;
        var textbox = document.createElement("input");
        textbox.setAttribute("type","text");
        textbox.setAttribute("id",i);
        document.body.appendChild(textbox);
    }
for(var j = 0; j <= textboxAmount; j++){ 
  add()
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bbx1Lfup/5/

Comment: html5 does allow you to use numbers as ids, you shouldn't use them for compatibility reasons  (if html4 is still of concern). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: @baao can you be a bit more specific? I don't know HTML too much in depth myself, but the topic he linked points directly to the spec which sais "the id attribute [...] must contain at least one character". I wouldn't doubt one second that browsers still run it anyways, but the answer "should not work" would be correct.

Comment: @ASDFGerte The answer he linked to is more than 10 years old and doesn't have any relevance in todays web developement. Check the link I posted to modern documentation

Comment: @baao [HTML 5.3 W3C Working Draft, 26 April 2018](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-html53-20180426/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id) - did apparently not change.

Comment: I think this is pretty clear (taken from the source you posted) _There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc._ @ASDFGerte

Comment: Maybe the wording means a digit it also a character? Anyways, thanks for elaborating, i guess the html spec is just confusing me a bit there.

Comment: Why confusing? :-) I haven't seen something more clear than the text in the big green box there... @ASDFGerte

Comment: @baao Yes, the spec is long and i rarely look at every part. I only followed links and therefore looked at the text block above only. Writing "[...] must contain [...] one character" to mean "cant be empty" was confusing me, especially because my non-native-english mind somehow concluded "character" was [A-Za-z] for a moment. Thanks for clearing that up - not remembering wrong information is very important, that's why i ask when being confused :)